# Redirect a domain already redirected

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain pointing to another like so:

`http://domain1.com` => `http://domain2.com/foo/bar`

`domain1.com` is being redirected at the dns level and I have no control/access.

I need to send traffic from `domain1.com/baz` to `domain2.com/baz` but keep getting a 404.

Right now, when you hit `domain1.com/baz` in the browser, it sends me to `domain2.com/foo/bar?q=baz`.

I tried adding `Redirect 301 /foo/bar?q=baz /baz` to my .htaccess but I still end up on `/foo/bar?q=baz` with a 404.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)q=([^&]+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^foo/bar$  /%2? [L]
```